# Underscore.js _.isElement function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have been looking underscore.js library functions and I noticed a function which returns whether the element is a DOM element or not. The function is below.

```
_.isElement = function(obj) {
    return !!(obj && obj.nodeType == 1);
};
```

Can you please tell me why `!!` is being used instead of just returning `(obj && obj.nodeType == 1)`. I am wondering whether `!!` adds any performance improvements. Any idea...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!!` forces the result to be a boolean.

If you pass `null`, for example, then the `&&` will return `null`.  The `!!` converts that to `false`.

If `obj` is "truthy", you'll get the result of `obj.nodeType == 1` which is a boolean.